# React not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, reactjs

While running Html file which uses React.js to display timer, its giving this error in Internet explorer

> If you can see this, React is not working right. If you checked out the source from GitHub make sure to run grunt.

I tried to search solution on google but i didnt got any.

Answer (score 3):

It appears React.js only supports Internet Explorer 8 and above. Are you using an older version of IE?

"At Facebook, we support older browsers, including IE8."  http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html

Comment: Worth noting from that page that es5-shim needs to be included to polyfill required JS functions in older browsers like IE8: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#polyfills-needed-to-support-older-browsers

Comment: I recommend [react-ie8](https://github.com/xcatliu/react-ie8)